# Cannot disable xpack security on ECK Elasticsearch helm deployment

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana

I'd like to start by saying that I'm not very good with Kubernetes and Helmchart, but I have a project and I need some help.

I'm having some issues with ECK.

I'm trying to deploy the ECK Operator, Kibana and Elasticsearch on my Kubernetes, but it seems Kibana cannot connect to Elasticsearch.

When I try to check Kibana logs, I see the following:

```
[ERROR][elasticsearch-service] Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. Request timed out
```

The weird thing is that if I try to log into Kibana pod and use the command:

```
curl -k -u "user:pass" -XGET https://eck-elasticsearch-es-http:9200/_cat/indices
```

there is no issue and I get the list of indexes.
`eck-elasticsearch-es-http` is the service automatically created by the helmchart.
This tells me that Kibana pod can connecto to Elasticsearch.

I think I managed to narrow it down on the **xpack.security** being **enabled**, even though I was expecting it to work since I'm using the default helmcharts with no particular customisations.

I wanted to test if it was in fact the xpack security, but I cannot disable it.
I tried changing the value.yml file in many different ways, but whenever I check the `eck-elasticsearch-es-default-es-config` secret where the elasticsearch.yml values are configured, I always see `xpack.security.enabled: "true"`. Also when trying to get in the Elasticsearch pod and checking the elasticearch.yml file, I see:

```
xpack:
    security:
        authc:
            realms:
                file:
                    file1:
                        order: -100
                native:
                    native1:
                        order: -99
            reserved_realm:
                enabled: "false"
        enabled: "true"
```

When deploying the Helmchart, I tried changing the following configurations in a values.yml file:

```
  containers:
  - name: elasticsearch
    config:
      xpack.security:
        enabled: false
```

or

```
elasticsearch:
  config:
    elasticsearch.yml: |
      # Elasticsearch configuration goes here
      xpack.security.enabled: false
```

I even tried using the env settings:

```
  containers:
  - name: elasticsearch
    env:
    - name: xpack.security.enabled
      value: "false"
```

In the official ECK guide I didn't find anything useful and I'm not sure what else to try.

I even thought about changing the `eck-elasticsearch-es-default-es-config` secret, but I cannot delete is since it gets recreated by helm.

Does anyone have any idea on how to disable the xpack security?

Thanks